# Use a 'for' loop with if/elif statement in Python list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am trying to translate this for loop into a list comprehension:

```py
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
result = []
for i in a:
    if i <= 3:
        result.append(1)
    elif i > 4 and i < 7:
        result.append(2)
```

and I have tried this

```
[1 if i <= 3 else 2 if i > 3 and i < 7 for i in a]
```

which complains about

```
File "<ipython-input-155-eebf07a9e0d8>", line 2
    [1 if i <= 3 else 2 if i > 3 and i < 7 for i in a]
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Oh also, the loop is different from the list comp. Try plugging in 4 for `i`.

Comment: `if i > 4 and i < 7` => `if 4 < i < 7` use chained comparison

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### List comprehension:

Add some more conditions :D (no this is really messy)

```py
[
    1 if i <= 3 else 2
    for i in a
    if i != 4 and i < 7
]
```

### How did we get here?

> Basic list comp: `[EXPRESSION for TARGET in ITERABLE if CONDITION]`
>
> Ternary expression: `(IF_TRUE if CONDITION else IF_FALSE)`

1. Get the for loop in. Simple enough `for i in a`.
2. Add conditions that filter out items which will be ignored. Once it gets past `CONDITION`, there has to be an item in the list at that position. In this case, we don't want `i` if it's 4 or greater than 7. `if i != 4 and i < 7`.
3. Do what you need with the item. In this case, we want `1` if `i` is smaller or equal to 4. Otherwise, we'll take 2. `1 if i <= 3 else 2`. Note: this is a ternary expression. Check them out!

Comment: could do with some more explanation of the filter/transformation parts but yes, correct

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, this works perfectly.