# Can we use for loop and if else in a single lambda function at once? so it can check values while working inside loop

Tags: python-3.x, conditional-statements

Have the function `LetterChanges(str)`. Take the `str` parameter being passed and modify it using the following algorithm. Replace every letter in the string with the letter following it in the alphabet (ie. c becomes d, z becomes a). 
Then capitalize every vowel in this new string (a, e, i, o, u) and finallyreturn this modified string.

I want this problem done in 2 lines

```
a= lambda stri:([(chr(ord(i) + 1)) for i in stri]) #if i not in ("a","e","i","o","u") 

print(a("bcdefgh"))
```

I know that if part is wrong, to understand clearly, I included it in comment.

Expected output is "cdEfgI".

Answer (score 0):

Your expected output does not match your input, you are missing an `h` before the final `I`.

Assuming this is just a typo, your problem can be solved with:

```py
>>> a = lambda stri: ''.join('A' if i == 'z' else chr(ord(i) + (-31 if i in "dhnt" else 1)) for i in stri)
>>> print(a("bcdefgh"))
cdEfghI
```

Explanation:

- first check if `i` is a `z` then return an `A`
- otherwise check if `i` is any character preceding a vowel in the alphabet then subtract 31 from it to get the capitalized vowel
- if that is not the case, increase the character by one

Answer (score 0):

Here's the normal code (that you should have already made):

```py
def change_letters(string):
    result = ''
    for letter in string:
        # This makes sure that 'z' goes to 'a'
        next_letter = chr((ord(letter) - 98)%26 + 97)
        if next_letter in 'aeiou':
            result += letter.upper()
        else:
            result += letter
    return string
```

If we follow the steps in my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56761611/use-for-loop-with-if-elif-statement-in-python-list-comprehension/56761659#56761659), we end up with the following:

```py
change_letters = lambda string: ''.join(chr((ord(letter) - 98)%26 + 97).upper() if chr((ord(letter) - 98)%26 + 97) in 'aeiou' else chr((ord(letter) - 98)%26 + 97) for letter in string)
```

But please note, this is a HORRIBLE thing to do, especially for your future self and others you may one day be working with. I would not want to see this again :)